# CSS External File is linking to the my html file from its own folder

Tags: html, css

Not sure why the external file not working?
**It works ONLY if I created it in the same folder with my HTML**, but when I created the CSS with its own folder it's not working. I'm asking because it works for other classmates but me.

[image: HTML file]

[image: CSS File]

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the css path as

> link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">

Answer (score 0):

To get to the `css` folder you will need to go back one folder level which can be done with `../`.

In this case you could change your `href` to `href="../css/styles.css"`.

**Or**

Because css is at the root of your project you could use `href="/css/styles.css"`.

**Or**

You should take your HTML files out of the `/image` folder and into the root of your project in `HTML - Personal Site/` and then you won't have to change the `href` property

Comment: @JesseG You should also consider taking the files out of the `image` folder, or renaming the folder for better description for what is inside it.

Comment: *** href="../css/styles.css"  that worked ***      I thought (what I was told)that if you use a CSS file and HTML file in the same folder you use  href="styles.css" and if they're in a separate file you would use href="css/styles.css".   But from what your saying is that the CSS is the root folder because it's above the other folders, hypothetically speaking if there were multiple files as well?

Comment: @JesseG it's because you have to step out of `image/` before you can step into `css/` if the html was outside of `image/` folder then you could use `href="css/styles.css"`. Have a read of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files

Comment: Yes great resource